# How to bypass the http.proxy that I have set using git config?

Tags: git, proxy

**Background**

The work computer that I have, I occasionally carry it at home. Now, we have a proxy server at work, and I have configured `git` to use it by doing `git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.company.com`. So when I get back at home, I do not require a proxy, so I need to unset the `http.proxy`. This is okay if I have to do it once in a while, but right now I need to do this every day: set the proxy, when I get to work, go home and unset the proxy, next day set it at work again.

**What I require**

A way to bypass the `http.proxy` that has been set, *individually in every command*. Something like a `--no-proxy` option:

```
git --no-proxy pull
```

I do *not* want to specify the proxy in every command, like:

```
git --proxy=http://proxy.company.com
```

because I do more `git`ting at work than I do at home.

Comment: For this reason, on my laptop i set on/off the proxy by OS (ubuntu gnome) and i haven't configured anything on git.

Comment: I don't think you can do that on Windows though. (Incidentally, how did you do it? `HTTP_PROXY` variable?)

Comment: Yeah `http_proxy` & `https_proxy` variables.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can either do exactly what you asked by using

```
git -c http.proxy= clone https://github.com/foo/bar.git
```

This will set the proxy to an empty value for this command and thus not use a proxy.

---

If it is not about cloning, but about fetching, pushing, pulling and so on, you can also add two remotes to your repository and then set `remote.<name>.proxy` accordingly. Then you use one remote at work and the other at home. As the commits are the same you should not have to download a commit twice even if it is on different remote tracking branches.

Comment: The `-c` option was what I was looking for. And the using different remotes is something I hadn't thought of. Haven't tried it yet, but thanks for that.

Comment: providing `http.proxy=` will result in a `error: Missing value for 'http.proxy'`

Comment: In which Git version? It worked for me and obviously for OP.

Comment: @ThadGuidry? It still works perfectly fine for me, would you mind answering my question?

Comment: @Vampire - on RHEL with git 1.8.3.1

Comment: How about updating your ancient (4 years old) Git version instead of downvoting a perfectly valid answer?

Comment: @Vampire - I tried your solution but got "error: key does not contain a section: http_proxy". Git version is  2.22.0.windows.1

Comment: It is `http.proxy`, not `http_proxy`

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if it will suit your needs, but you can set up proxy for specific urls in such way:

```
[http "<matching url>"]
    proxy = <url>
```

For example: I am behind proxy at work and want to access projects on github, so I add following section to my `~/.gitconfig` (note, that I use fake username "proxy" in matching url):

```
[http "https://proxy@github.com/"]
    proxy = https://10.144.1.10:8080/
```

From now on, whenever I want to access any server without proxy - I do it as usual. When I want to access server over proxy, I add fake "proxy" username in front.

This will stall when I am behind proxy, but work otherwise:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/project/path.git
```

This will work behind proxy:

```
$ git clone https://proxy@github.com/project/path.git
```

To make `fetch`, `pull` and `push` work - you will need to add 2 remotes (one for proxy, one without proxy) and use accordingly.

Comment: Yes, this is a valid solution, but I think I like the `-c` option more.

Comment: Instead of using an address, I used an empty string and it worked  `proxy =`

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar situation by writing a Bash script that simply turns the proxy on and off by setting the `http.proxy` configuration variable:

```
#!/bin/sh

proxy="http://host:port"

if [[ $(git config --global http.proxy) ]]; then
    git config --global --unset http.proxy
    echo "Git is not using a proxy"
else
    git config --global http.proxy $proxy
    echo "Git is using the proxy at $proxy"
fi
```

I called the script `flip_git_proxy` and put it in the path. Now, each time I start a new Bash session I simply run:

At work:

```
$ flip_git_proxy
Git is using the proxy at http://host:post
```

At home:

```
$ flip_git_proxy
Git is not using a proxy
```

Comment: Well, I wanted a way to ignore the proxy during every command and only for the duration of the command. Anyways, I don't get the point of this script. Wouldn't I rather just do `git config --global --unset http.proxy`? Why do I need a script for that? Plus, I'd need another script for Windows, and I don't like cmd enough, and I don't know enough of PowerShell.

Comment: @JohnRed It doesn't really matter if you ignore the proxy only for the duration of certain commands, since the only time Git uses the network is during `clone`, `fetch` and `push` so you might as well set it at the beginning of your session. Personally, I found that running that simple script is faster than composing the commands to set/unset the proxy. Finally, that script works with Bash on Windows.