# Using Git via Proxy

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, gitlab

I am trying to use git (Micorsoft vsts git repo) via Proxy, but when I when run a command like this

```
git pull origin master
```

i get this error:

> unable to access 'https://bcmlogic.visualstudio.com/_git/XXX/': Failed to connect to XXX.visualstudio.com port 443: Timed out

How can i use git while i am using bypassproxy behind sense, i cannot disable it because i have internet there.

Comment: Do you want to bypass git from the proxy?

Comment: yes,exactly to be like this

Comment: Agree with GR8's answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41440395/11508165

Answer (score 0):

You can set the proxy to an empty value for this command:

```
git -c http.proxy= pull origin master
```